Not able to Access S3 image via Cloudfront
I have created S3 bucket with public access with below mentioned Bucket policy and CORS. My bucket image is accessible in my web app.
But When I create cloudfront distribution for this bucket with default settings, I am not able to access bucket image using https://demoid.cloudfront.net/bucket_image.png in my web app.
Bucket policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DemoSid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

CORS:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]


What do you mean by "not able to access"? What happens?

S3 bucket image does not render in HTML img tag with cloudfront domain url

Does it work if you remove the Condition section? What were you actually hoping that condition would do?

Ohh Yes :) it's working without Condition. I used this to specify my web domain address so that image can only be accessed by my web app.

Referer offers very poor security. It is best avoided. See: Referer spoofing - Wikipedia

@JohnRotenstein Then How can I restrict access to only my web app? Is it necessary to use cloudfront for this? Thankyou for your support.

If you are serving static content from Amazon S3, it's not easy to restrict access to content. This is the same for any website. You either put content behind login authentication run by a back-end server or make your content public. Or, an in-between option: Password Protection for Static Websites on AWS S3 • notes on software.
